# Kunneth formula for hypercohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-categories

Let $A_{\bullet}$ and $B_{\bullet}$ be two bounded complexes of sheaves over a variety $X$. Is there a Kunneth-like formula for the hypercohomology of the tensor product $A_{\bullet}\otimes B_{\bullet}$? How to recover the hypercohomology of $A_{\bullet}\otimes B_{\bullet}$ from the hypercohomologies of the complexes $A_{\bullet}$ and $B_{\bullet}$, in practice, even for the simplest case when $B_{\bullet}$ is just a rank 1 locally free sheaf?

Comment: Heve a look at Iversen's book "*Cohomology of sheaves*"  Sec. VII.2.

Comment: The sheaf $A=B=\mathcal{O}(-1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ has vanishing cohomology in all degrees, while $A\otimes B=A\otimes^LB=\mathcal{O}(-2)$ has nonzero $H^1$. So there is no such formula.